# Problems with dragging element in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

These are my javascript, css, and html files for simple web page for dragging an element and putting it into the container(div) :

```js
var xContainer;
var yContainer
var insideFirst = false;
$(window).load(
        function() {
            xContainer = $("#center").offset().left;
            yContainer = $("#center").offset().top;
            console.log("ready");
            $("#center").on("click", function(event) {
                console.log(event);
            });
            $("#center").droppable();
            $("#firstID").draggable({
                cursor : 'move',
                revert: "invalid"
            });
            $("#firstID").mousedown(function() {
                isDragging = false;
            }).mousemove(
                    function() {
                        isDragging = true;
                        var x = $("#firstID").offset().left;
                        var y = $("#firstID").offset().top;
                        xContainer = $("#center").offset().left;
                        yContainer = $("#center").offset().top;
                        var xPosition = (x - xContainer).toFixed(2);
                        var yPosition = (y - yContainer).toFixed(2);
                        console.log("center:" + xContainer);
                        console.log("x:" + x);
                        console.log("difference: "+(x-xContainer));
                        /*
                         * if (x < 750 && y < 750) {
                         * $("#firstID").css('background','#ffffff') }
                         */
                        if (xPosition >= 0.0 && yPosition >= 0.0
                                && xPosition <= 500.0 && yPosition <= 200.0) {
                            $("#xPosition").val("x:" + xPosition);
                            $("#yPosition").val("y:" + yPosition);
                            $("#firstID").css('background', '#e4e4e4')
                            $('#firstID').draggable({containment : [xContainer,yContainer,xContainer+500,yContainer+200.0] });
                        } else {
                            //$("#xPosition").val("GO IN!!!");
                            //$("#yPosition").val("GO IN!!!");
                            $("#firstID").css('background', '#d1f1fc')
                        }

                    }).mouseup(function() {
                var wasDragging = isDragging;
                isDragging = false;
                if (!wasDragging) {
                    console.log("clicked");
                }

            });
            $("#secondID").draggable({
                cursor : 'move'
            });
            $("#secondID").mousedown(function() {
                isDragging = false;
            }).mousemove(function() {
                isDragging = true;
                var x = $("#secondID").offset().left;
                var y = $("#secondID").offset().top;
                // $("#text-x").val ("x:"+x);
                // $("#text-y").val ("y:"+y);
            }).mouseup(function() {
                var wasDragging = isDragging;
                isDragging = false;
                if (!wasDragging) {
                    console.log("clicked");
                }

            });
            $("#secondID").dblclick(function() {
                rotation += 90;
                $(this).rotate(rotation);
            });
        });
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });
    return $(this);
};
var rotation = 0;
var isDragging = false;
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;

}

#firstID {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: groove;
    background-color: #d1f1fc;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}

#secondID {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    border-style: groove;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d1f1fc;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}

#center {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: groove;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

/* If in mobile screen with maximum width 479px. The iPhone screen resolution is 320x480 px (except iPhone4, 640x960) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #center{
        width: 50%;
        height : 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drag.css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="xPosition" value="x:0">
<input type="text" id="yPosition" value="y:0">
<div id="firstID" >MJ</div>
<div id="secondID" >MJ</div>
<div id="center">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is not finished, so the logic works with only a square, not rectangle.
What i need is to drag square element into the container on the page and make it stay inside it, with no possibility to leave it. That works fine in Mozilla, but in Chrome, i have problems with dragging the square after entering container. When i click on it and try to drag it, it moves far to the right side of the page. Why is that happening only in Chrome?